# Как настроить htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Имеется сайт на неопределенной CMS (предположительно parallels), у него в корне лежит htaccess, в котором мне мешает жить одна строчка

```
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html|swf|flv|zip|pdf|txt|doc|xls|rar|htm|htc|psd)$ site.php
```

из-за нее я не пойму как мне запустить php скрипт, если строчку убрать, то скрипт работает, но перестает работать сайт и наоборот...

подскажите, как, куда можно засунуть php, чтобы он завелся? или может можно исключение какое прописать? Очень нужно, пожалуйста! Спасибо )

Comment: Твое правило гласит, что все, что указано `(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html|swf|flv|zip|pdf|txt|doc|xls|rar|htm|htc|psd)` должно перенаправлять на `site.php`. То есть по идеи, ты можешь выполнять свои PHP скрипты... Попробуй еще добавить, если нет, строку `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Comment: не помогает, может он как-то меняет адрес по которому я обращаюсь к файлу? изображения из этой же папки отображаются, а на стрипт при наличии этой строки ругается...